# Magento2.3 - How to Sort Products Based on Attribute Category

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch

Is it possible to add an order by category attribute in the search catalog?

I would like to add search relevance based on category positions. 
For example if I search Iphone the result returns to me: iphone case (whose category accessory) and then apple iphone (whose category gsm).

However I would like the result to display the products with the category gsm and then the category accessory, the result would be: apple iphone 7, apple iphone 8 and then iphone 7 case etc.